# Eclipse - how to change background color of selected file, when Project Explorer View is inactive

Tags: eclipse, darkmode

I can't see which file is selected in the Project Explorer view when the view is inactive, as the image shows. 
Someone can help me to change the background color of selected file? 
*Windows 10 

Eclipse 2021-03 

Dark theme*

[image: background color not visible]

I would like something like was in the old Eclipse:

[image: in old eclipse]
*Windows 8.1 

Eclipse 2018-12*

Comment: The selection colours are defined by the OS so Eclipse does not have a setting for this.

Comment: Excuse me Greg, but in previous Eclipse version there was a color who highlighted the file clearly, so I think that Eclipse could/should control this color!

Comment: up voted question. I use the same OS, just upgraded to newer Eclipse version. 4.20 to be exact. And I have the same problem. Actually, if you look closely there is a slightly lighter background. You can even see it in the upper picture when the view is not active. But its so similar to the background that it might as well not be there.

Comment: @DanielePrivitera did you managed to find a solution for this?

Comment: @GonçaloCardoso the only Solution that I found to this problem is to use an old version of Eclipse, so right now I'm using-> Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0), that has not that problem (so it's very better, for me ; )

Answer (score 3):

I am dealing with the same problem... As a workaround you can take a look at `e4-dark_partstyle.css` file and make the background a little bit darker so the selection is visible. The key here is to know what element to modify. I have changed the `background-color` of a bunch of elements (including the one I think is related to package and project explorers, called `Tree`) from `#2F2F2F` to `#171717`.

Hope it helps.

[image: css modification]

Original:
[image: Original]

Modified:
[image: Modified]

Comment: thank you a lot Luis for the suggestion. At the moment I'm using the old Eclipse to solve this problem. But in future if will need I'll try your solution ;)

Comment: still works for me 2 years later in Version: 2023-12 - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you will have to mess with the CSS file a lot! (My modified Eclipse/spring pic below).

What I would advice, is to head to the css folder for the dark theme (F:\STS\sts-4.20.1.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.2300.v20230807-1354\css\dark), save a copy of the file, and just replace the hex colors! The file that changes the editor and console is: e4-dark_partstyle.css and the file that changes the tool bars is: e4-dark_ide_colorextensions.css

[Modified SpringTools picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvdwU.png)